# Draw rectangle in picture box C#

Tags: c#, draw, picturebox, drawrectangle

I have an application that shows different images in a pictureBox. There are a few other picture boxes that do other things and I want to keep the default paint method.
When the image is correct I have to draw a green rectangle and when the image is incorrect I don't have to do anything.

I have seen that it is needed to override the paint method to draw rectangles but if I override the method it will always draw the green rectangle.

EDIT:

I have written this method:

```
private void pictureBox_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{            
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(e.ClipRectangle.X, e.ClipRectangle.Y, e.ClipRectangle.Width, e.ClipRectangle.Height);
    e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(new Pen(Color.Green, 20), rect);
}
```

And I call add the event to it like this:

```
pbFrontView.Paint += pictureBox_Paint;
pbLeftView.Paint += pictureBox_Paint;
```

So, I have many picture boxes and different images (this is in my main function)

```
if(drawRectanglePbFront)
    //Draw rectangle in pbFrontView
if(drawRectanglePbLeft)
    //Draw rectangle in pbLeft
...
```

Is there any way to know which pinture box has invoked "pictureBox_Paint" ? If, yes I could move "if(drawRectanglePbFront) ..." inside of "pictureBox_Paint" and manage everything there

Comment: How about overriding `OnPaint` (or registering the `Paint` event) but only drawing the green rectangle if a flag is set? And setting this flag according to the correctness of the image?

Comment: Good idea, but I cannot set a global flag to do this in this project

Comment: "always draw the green rectangle" is not true, if you need it, then draw it, if you dont need it, then dont draw it.

Comment: Not a global but class level data are needed to control dynamic drawing. Or you can call afunction that know about which pbox is the correct one.

Comment: And your question is? Show us what you have and what is not working.

Comment: _which piсture box has invoked_ - `sender` is this picture box.

Comment: sender? how do I use the sender to know the pictureBox? I cannot find anything with the name of the pincturebox in the sender

Comment: Cast sender to PictureBox: `var pb = (PictureBox)sender;`